# iOS Swift 3: Comparing One all elements of Array in another array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have struct model like

```
struct ModelA {
    let text: String
    let id: Int
}

extension ModelA: Equatable {}

func ==(lhs: ModelA, rhs: ModelA) -> Bool {
    let areEqual = lhs.id == rhs.id
    return areEqual
}
```

i have created arrays of this model

```
let a1:[ModelA] = [ModelA(text: "10", id: 11), ModelA(text: "11", id: 12)]
let a2:[ModelA] = [ModelA(text: "11", id: 12)]
```

and having a comparing function

```
func isEqualArray(first array1: [Any], second array2: [Any]) -> Bool {
     let set1 = NSSet(array: array1)
     let set2 = NSSet(array: array2)
     return set1.isSubset(of: set2 as! Set<AnyHashable>)
}
```

so when i'm trying to cross check

```
 let flag = isEqualArray(first: a1, second: a2)
 print("### \(flag)")
```

It crashes on function return

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your struct needs to conform to `hashable` as well as `equatable`

Comment: why are you using `NSSet` instead of Swift sets? And any time you use ! you are asking for your code to crash if the downcast fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct needs to conform to both `equatable` and `hashable` in order to be used in a `Set`.  It seems that you only care about the `id`, so a simple implementation would be:

```
struct ModelA {
    let text: String
    let id: Int
}

extension ModelA: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: ModelA, rhs: ModelA) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}

extension ModelA: Hashable {
    var hashValue: Int {
        return id
    }
}
```

Now, you can use Swift sets in your `isEqualArray` function; you also need to consider which set is smaller since you are using `isSubSet(of:)`:

```
func isEqualArray(first array1: [AnyHashable], second array2: [AnyHashable]) -> Bool {

    let set1: Set<AnyHashable>
    let set2: Set<AnyHashable>

    if array1.count > array2.count {
        set1 = Set(array1)
        set2 = Set(array2)
    } else {
        set1 = Set(array2)
        set2 = Set(array1)
    }
    return set2.isSubset(of: set1)
}
```

Your code actually determines if one array is a subset of another, not if the arrays are equal, so I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: As I said, your code is using `isSubSet(Of:)`, so you need to know which array is larger, a larger set cannot be a subset of a smaller set